# Kamailio installation error on MAC 10.9, what is this error?

Tags: macos, sip, sip-server, kamailio

I am trying install `Kamailio 4.1` on mac OS10.9 by command:

```
make cfg; make all; make install
```

But I see on Terminal, it through:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/kamailio/
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [install-cfg] Error 2
```

What is this error? Do I missing anything else? Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Looks to me like the makefile is corrupted in some way. Maybe it has DOS newlines instead of Unix newlines.

Comment: I can install kamailio on CentOS. How can I change it to run on my MAC?

Answer (score 2):

Not clear from provided log messages, but I expect is about file system privileges. You need to run 'make install' via sudo (or as a privileged user that can create the directory /usr/local/etc/kamailio/).

I use kamailio on mac os x for few years now. Apart of installing some libraries via mac ports for various modules, all runs smooth.